Is jewelry with depictions of golems permitted
It only recently hit me that this can be problematic as it sort of has an image of a face on it and can be considered an idol? Does it make a difference if one’s intention is purely for decorative/symbolic purposes, and not for idol worship?
I attached a link with photo as an example. Please share your halakhic thoughts.
Thank you
https://www.etsy.com/listing/1691907885/

https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.141.5?lang=bi&with=all
